# Why do I get a heap buffer overflow simply by declaring a shared_ptr member variable?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, heap-corruption, address-sanitizer

Just ran into this very strange bug.  I'm getting crashes due to memory errors after adding a new `shared_ptr` instance variable in an existing containing class.

When I run with the AddressSanitizer in Xcode, it reports a heap buffer overflow on the new iVar, when an object of the containing class is instantiated (i.e., at its CTOR).

I can't replicate this in a simple system, and this is proprietary code (so I can't show it fully here).  ***However, I can trigger the error simply by declaring a new shared_ptr instance variable, of a simple type (int).***

My classes are basically

```
// MyContainingClass.h

#include <memory>

// Forward
class HelperObject;

class MyContainingClass {

public:
    MyContainingClass();
 ...

private:
    std::shared_ptr<HelperObject> _helperObject;
};
```

```
//MyContainingClass.cpp

#include "HelperObject.h"

...

MyContainingClass::MyContainingClass() {
    _helperObject = std::make_shared<HelperObject>();
}

...
```

and that runs fine.  But when I try this (adding one line: the new iVar)

```
// MyContainingClass.h

#include <memory>

// Forwards
class HelperObject;
class DifferentHelperObject;

class MyContainingClass {

public:
    MyContainingClass();
 ...

private:
    std::shared_ptr<HelperObject> _helperObject;
    std::shared_ptr<DifferentHelperObject> _differentHelperObject; // <- NEW LINE
};
```

I get a heap buffer overflow at the MyContainingClass CTOR, *even without trying to allocate the DifferentHelperObject.*. (I get the same error if I *do* create the smart pointer in the CTOR.)

*If I change the order of declaration*, AddressSanitizer reports the error at `HelperObject` instead of `DifferentHelperObject` (i.e., whichever one is declared second).

DifferentHelperObject is a fairly simple type; it contains only simple POD members and methods (no pointers, arrays, smart pointers, etc.)  So I tried replacing it with something *really* simple: a `std::shared_ptr<int>`:

```
    std::shared_ptr<HelperObject> _helperObject;
    std::shared_ptr<int> _anInt; //Adding just this line to otherwise working code causes a crash
```

and I now get the heap buffer overflow on the shared_ptr for `_anInt.`

This is what the AddressSanitizer output looks like for the last case:

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXX/MyApp.app/MyApp:arm64+0x10aa0e120) in std::__1::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr()+0x4c
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0002a56ea260: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0002a56ea270: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0002a56ea280: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0002a56ea290: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0002a56ea2a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0002a56ea2b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0002a56ea2c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0002a56ea2d0: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0002a56ea2e0: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0002a56ea2f0: fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0002a56ea300: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
AddressSanitizer report breakpoint hit. Use 'thread info -s' to get extended information about the report.
(lldb) thread info -s
thread #1: tid = 0xb9794, 0x000000012446b328 libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie(), queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Heap buffer overflow

{
  "access_size": 8,
  "access_type": 1,
  "address": 5023012304,
  "description": "heap-buffer-overflow",
  "instrumentation_class": "AddressSanitizer",
  "pc": 4543308068,
  "stop_type": "fatal_error"
}
(lldb)
```

[image: The actuall error, when using AddressSanitizer]

and the call stack looks like this:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000012446b328 in __asan::AsanDie() ()
#1  0x000000012448096c in __sanitizer::Die() ()
#2  0x000000012446890c in __asan::ScopedInErrorReport::~ScopedInErrorReport() ()
#3  0x000000012446813c in __asan::ReportGenericError(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, unsigned int, bool) ()
#4  0x000000012446943c in __asan_report_store8 ()
#5  0x000000010ecd6124 in std::__1::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr() at /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2983
#6  0x000000010ecd119c in std::__1::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr() at /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2985
#7  0x000000010ecd0f08 in MyContainingClass::MyContainingClass() at /Users/xxx/MyContainingClass.cpp:22
#8  0x000000010ecd1870 in MyContainingClass::MyContainingClass() at /Users/xxx/MyContainingClass.cpp:22
```

I've been trying to understand the AddressSanitizer output; the shadow memory addresses don't seem to map correctly onto actual program memory (mutliplying by 8, there is still an offset.  So any help understanding how the AddressSanitizer output above could point me to the actual problem (or suggestions what the actual problem might be) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How/Where do you create the `MyContainingClass`?

Comment: Just to get the simple possibility out of the way:  does the fault go away if you do a full/clean rebuild of your program?  (I’ve seen this sort of thing occur when the build system neglected to rebuild some .o files that have a dependency on the data-layout of a class whose layou has changed)

Comment: @tkausl MyContainingClass is itself a shared_ptr, created in the first line of an initializer method of another, outer containing class:

    _myContainer = std::make_shared<MyContainingClass>();

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Y, exact same error after a full clean & rebuild (but a good question to ask)

Comment: This needs a [mre]. I guess there is already UB somewhere and adding the member just makes it visible.

Comment: The code provided does not produce the problem cited.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned initially, I haven't been able to replicate this in a simple system (I've tried.  The code above shows the *structure* of the code in question, and the breaking change.)  That's why I asked for helped interpreting the AddressSanitizer output above to point me toward the actual problem.

Comment: @bphi if you haven't already and can do so, you might try running the code under valgrind and see if it points you to any interesting memory-access problems.  (FWIW I've had good luck running valgrind under Linux but less luck running it under MacOS/X, so hopefully your code is portable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, as @user17732522 mentioned, it was a symptom, not the problem itself.

I had static library and executable linked with the library. Both library and executable included the same header file:

```
class Config
{
 public:
  bool foo;
  bool bar;
#if defined(DEFINITION)
  bool baz;
#endif
};
```

`DEFINITION` was defined in library and not defined in the executable

So the following class:

```
class Class {
// ...
private:
 Config config_;
 std::shared_ptr<int> obj1_;
 std::shared_ptr<HelperObject> obj2_;
}
```

produced the same ASan error:

```
=================================================================
==7202==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60c000000180 at pc 0x000000c33b5d bp 0x7ffc29bc1da0 sp 0x7ffc29bc1d98
WRITE of size 8 at 0x60c000000180 thread T0
    #0 0xc33b5c in std::__1::shared_ptr<HelperObject>::shared_ptr() /usr/local/include/c++/v1/memory:4047:7
```

Answer (score 1):

> very strange bug. I'm getting crashes due to memory errors after adding a new shared_ptr instance variable in an existing containing class.

> I can't replicate this in a simple system

Quite often this is the result of rebuilding some, *but not all* of the code which includes `MyContainingClass.h`.

Try doing a "from scratch" build. Chances are, both the crash and the AddressSanitizer problems will disappear.